# Toggle only once

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question for you  regarding the **.toggle()** function :

### How to toggle only one time ?

I have an event bind to the resize of my windows and want on my element to be displayed or not.

I know I can do that with media-queries and css very easily (and this is probably better) but actually I'd like to know how to get it done by jQuery.

I've tried to use the function .one() but I didn't get really how this is suppose to work.

### Here is my jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(changeClass);
jQuery(window).resize(changeClass);

function changeClass() {
   if($(window).width() < 805){
   $('.test').one(toggle());
}
```

What am I doing wrong ?

And, as an answer to my question if people ever have this problem one day; here is the answer in **pure CSS**

```
@media(max-width:805px)
{
   .test{
      display:none;
   }
}
```

Comment: try this. call $('.test').toggle() and then set it to $('.test').toggle =false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of your pure CSS in jQuery is:

```
jQuery(window).on('resize load', changeClass);

function changeClass() {
    $('.test').toggle(window.matchMedia('(max-width:805px)').matches);
}
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: @Umair I'm not a search engine... http://caniuse.com/#feat=matchmedia  If you want to support older browser, check for window width but take into account scrollbars